# I'm trying to strip out anything before '=' as well as specific words

Tags: php, regex

I have an array that I need to go through, Take out everything before '=' including the '=' as well as certain words.  Then separate the rest of the contents of the array by ','.
Here are the contents of the array: $rows['role']

```
$rows['role'][0] = cn=Service Desk Customer,ou=Groups,dc=,dc=co,dc=uk
$rows['role'][1] = cn=User,ou=Groups,dc=,dc=co,dc=uk
$rows['role'][2] = cn=Site Administrator,ou=Groups,ou=Kiev,ou=Ukraine,ou=Euro-Med,dc=,dc=co,dc=uk
$rows['role'][3] = cn=Agent Biometric,ou=Groups,ou=Tirana,ou=Albania,ou=Euro-Med,dc=,dc=co,dc=uk
$rows['role'][4] = cn=Agent Welcome,ou=Groups,ou=Tripoli,ou=Libya,ou=Euro-Med,dc=,dc=co,dc=uk
```

After that, I need to sort the results into two arrays, one for role, including Service Desk Customer, Site Administrator, etc. and one for location that will include Tripoli, Libya, Albania.

I would like to end up with a $roles string or array that only contains items such as Service Desk Customer, Site Administrator, ect. and then a $location string or array that contains all of the location information.

Here is what I have so far.  I'm able to remove everything I'm looking to remove so far.  The only trouble I'm having is pulling items starting with cn= to a $roles variable (preferably with cn= removed) and ou= to a $locations variable.

```
$removes = array( 'dc=','ou=Groups','cn=User','dc=co','dc=uk');



        $rows[$i] = array(
            'picture'   => $jpeg,
            'first'     => $info[$i]["givenname"][0],
            'last'      => $info[$i]["sn"][0],
            'mail'      => $info[$i]["mail"][0],
            //'role'        => $info[$i]["memberof"][0],
        );
        foreach($info[$i]['memberof'] as $key => $value){
            $replace = str_replace($removes,'',$value);
            $rows[$i]['role'][$key] = $replace;
        }
        array_filter($rows[$i]['role']);

        print_r ($rows[$i]['role']);
    }
    ldap_close($ds)
```

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: It will be helpful if you could give a sample output as well

Comment: I would like to end up with a roles array, displaying everything that is starting with a 'cn=' only without the cn= like $roles = 'Site Administrator, Service Desk Customer, Agent Biometric'; and then a locations array with everything starting with ou= minus the ou, like $location = 'Kiev, Ukraine, Euro-Med, Tirana, Albaina'; I would like to remove all cn= amd ou=, as well as certain words like Groups, User, dc=tpcontact, dc=co, and dc=uk

Comment: there should be an DN parser out there.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Added what i've gotten so far, the only think I haven't been able to do is search the array for items containing cn= and putting those items in their own array..

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
foreach ($rows['role'] as $r) {
   print_r ( explode(',', preg_replace('/(^|,)\K[^=]*=/', '', $r)) );
}
```

For first 2 rows it gives this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Service Desk Customer
    [1] => Groups
    [2] => domain
    [3] => co
    [4] => uk
)
Array
(
    [0] => User
    [1] => Groups
    [2] => domain
    [3] => co
    [4] => uk
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$result = array_map(function ($val) {
                        return substr($val,3, strpos($val, ',') - 3 ); },
                    $rows['role']);

print_r($result);
```