# Separate items in an array to their own array based on the first three characters

Tags: php, regex

I have this array:

```
Array ( 
[count] => 5 
[0] => cn=Service Desk Customer,ou=Groups,dc=,dc=co,dc=uk 
[1] => cn=User,ou=Groups,dc=,dc=co,dc=uk 
[2] => cn=Site Administrator,ou=Groups,ou=Kiev,ou=Ukraine,ou=Euro-Med,dc=,dc=co,dc=uk 
[3] => cn=Agent Biometric,ou=Groups,ou=Tirana,ou=Albania,ou=Euro-Med,dc=,dc=co,dc=uk 
[4] => cn=Agent Welcome,ou=Groups,ou=Tripoli,ou=Libya,ou=Euro-Med,dc=,dc=co,dc=uk )
```

I'm using this to try to remove everything starting with 'cn=' and place it into it's own $roles array. but it's only returning [count] => 5.

```
$search = preg_grep('/cn=/', $rows[$i]['role']);
$roles = preg_grep('/cn=/',$rows[$i]['role'],PREG_GREP_INVERT);
print_r ($roles);
```

Comment: I just realized that I all the items start with cn=

Comment: Didn't you already have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884071/im-trying-to-strip-out-anything-before-as-well-as-specific-words